# How to use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP?

Tags: perl, smtp

If I use: `my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new(some parameters)`

PERL says: `Can't locate object method "new" via package "Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP"`

And yes, there is no sub `new` inside SMTP.pm

---

- Windows server 2008 64 bit.
- Apache 2.2.21 64 bit.
- Activestate PERL 5.14.2 64 bit.
- Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::VERSION = '1.300012';

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The module Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP is based on [Moo](http://search.cpan.org/~haarg/Moo-1.005000/). Those [Moo](http://search.cpan.org/~haarg/Moo-1.005000/) framework will create the new sub automatically. So its okay that you dont find a new sub in the SMTP.pm file itself.

Do you have added the proper load statement for Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP to your source files?

```
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP;
```

The mentioned error message comes up if the related module dont got loaded, e.g.

```
perl -e "my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new();"
Can't locate object method "new" via package "Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP"
```

vs.

```
perl -e "use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP; my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new();"
[ALL OK]
```